# How to get Process name by Python?

Tags: python

I want to get process name (ex:notepad.exe) by using win32 api in Python ,
so the code like ,

```
hwnd = FindWindow(None,"123.txt - notepad")
threadid ,pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
print('pid=' + str(pid))
handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid)
proc_name = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(handle, 0)
```

but the exception occur ,

```
pywintypes.error: (299, 'GetModuleFileNameEx', 'ReadProcessMemory
or WriteProcessMemory ....exception')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit modified code from pywinauto getting executable path and name of the process using PyWin32 only:

```
hwnd = FindWindow(None,"123.txt - notepad")
threadid, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
print('pid=' + str(pid))

from win32com.client import GetObject
_wmi = GetObject('winmgmts:')

# collect all the running processes
processes = _wmi.ExecQuery('Select * from win32_process')
for p in processes:
    if isinstance(p.ProcessId, int) and p.ProcessId == pid:
        print((p.ProcessId, p.ExecutablePath, p.CommandLine, p.Name))
```

No need to install `WMI` or `psutil`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`wmi`](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) python module or expose the [`WMIC`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command line utility to get the list of active processes.

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for process in c.Win32_Process ():
  print process.ProcessId, process.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [psutil](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil), it's more simpler and pythonic: [`psutil.Process().name()`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.name) , and it will work on both Windows and POSIX.

Comment: thanks,I know I can use psutil , but can I use win32 api directly ?